# Modelling timeseries data for sensors and gateways in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have data coming in from IoT gateways every 30 seconds in the below format.

```
[
    {
        gateway: "G1",
        sensor: "S1",
        timestamp: T1
    },
    {
        gateway: "G1",
        sensor: "S2",
        timestamp: T2
    },
    {
        gateway: "G2",
        sensor: "S1",
        timestamp: T3
    },
    {
        gateway: "G2",
        sensor: "S1",
        timestamp: T4
    },
    {
        gateway: "G1",
        sensor: "S1",
        timestamp: T5
    },
    {
        gateway: "G2",
        sensor: "S1",
        timestamp: T6
    }
]
```

My objective is to figure out the following

1. The latest gateway to which a specific sensor has pinged
2. A list of the durations for which a sensor has pinged to different gateways

Eg, if we are taking S1 into consideration, I am expecting something along the lines of the following

```
[
    {
        gateway: "G1"
        duration: T2 - T1
    },
    {
        gateway: "G2",
        duration: T6 - T3
    }
]
```

I am new to mongo timeseries data modelling. Is this a correct usecase for Mongo timeseries collection? If yes, how can I model and query the data for the above use cases?

Also, can these be achieved in Mongo using normal collections? Any pointers towards the querying strategy would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `$group`ing on the `$gateway` and selecting the min and max timestamp values, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      sensor: "S1"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$gateway",
      minTimestamp: {
        $min: "$timestamp"
      },
      maxTimestamp: {
        $max: "$timestamp"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      gateway: "$_id",
      duration: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $toString: "$minTimestamp"
          },
          "-",
          {
            $toString: "$maxTimestamp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lsEp5JgXT9w)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. But this doesn't solve the problem entirely. My objective is to create a timeline based on the different gateways a sensor has pinged to. If we take the min and max timestamps, then it will be giving incorrect results, as there can be multiple other gateways to which the sensor has pinged, between the min and max timestamps

Also, can you please suggest if this makes for a good use case for storing in the new timeseries collections?